# mud/paint wearing off

Tags: ceiling, painting, sanding, paint-removal, drywall-mud

This is a follow up question to
[meshed tape exposed on sanding](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/221495/meshed-tape-exposed-on-sanding/264740#264740)

One year after the above job was completed (apply mud and sanding and painting), I see this happening. The mud/paint which was applied is wearing off (not sure if its mud or paint).

[image]
Not sure what is causing this and how to fix it now to avoid this in future.
Any responses will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks all in advance.

Comment: There is probably some moisture that's causing a lot of the trouble.

Comment: Yeah, that kinda looks like efflorescence.